# make post request to get json data in php

Tags: php, http-post

I'm trying to make a post request in php to the url which returns json data as string.
My code is:

```
$url = "http://mysite.xxx/getjson/";
$method = 'POST';
$request = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'    => "Content-type: application/html\r\nAccept: */*\r\n",
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'content'   => http_build_query($params)
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($request);
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $json;
```

And I am getting nothing
I have checked the code in url and I think the post parameters are not being passed.
Can anyone help me with it.
Thank you!

Comment: what is in your variable `$params`

Comment: There is no certainty for us that the problem is not originating from the server delivering the JSON.

Comment: I have array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2') in $params

Comment: I have used Advanced REST Client (chrome extension) to check the code in the url and it is working fine.. What I just need to do is send the post variables cuz' I'm getting error message I had set in the code in url with above code due to missing POST Variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as your content type:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: I have tried it but I am getting "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable" warning

Comment: Done and still getting same warning

Comment: Thats the server being picky about the content it is able to respond with.  Can you create an endpoint so we can test this ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Try using cURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://mysite.xxx/getjson/",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $params,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: application/json'
   )
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);

$result     = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);

print_r(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. The code is working when I tested with other endpoint code. But I don't understand why my first endpoint code was working when I tested with Advanced Rest Client(chrome extension). I have to find that out. Anyway, Thank you guyz for response